# How do you write the css for these divs?

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have a banner in three parts, part1 and part3 are curved edge images and part2 is the horizontal rectangle image. It would look like

```
part1 ... part2 ... part3
```

part1 and part3 are the dimensions of their image, but part2 should have a repeating background image such that the div of part2's width adjusts to the width of the browser so that the banner can be adjusted to any width browser.  How do you write the css for these three divs such that they, together, create a banner of any length?

Comment: Google 'sliding doors css' for a slightly better way of handling this using the same concepts. (Or, if all you need are rounded corners, consider doing this with one DIV and use CSS to round the corners)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

See [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/Rac76/1/).

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    height: 120px;
    background: url('middle-part-of-banner.png') repeat-x;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.banner span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url('end-parts-of-banner.png') no-repeat;
}
.banner span+span {
    background-position: -580px 0;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using :before and :after for these kinds of things. It keeps the HTML clean and makes more sense in my head.

HTML:

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#banner {
  height: 100px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1/100) repeat-x left top;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1
}

#banner:before, #banner:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#banner:before {
  left: 0;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) no-repeat left top;
}

#banner:after {
  right: 0;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) no-repeat left top;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/3BapK/

Comment: You forgot to mention that `:after` and `:before` don't work in IE7.

Comment: Yes, IE7 likes to rain on my parades.

Answer (score 0):

You might try with style for the middle BG.

Can you try this? You might need slight adustments of other style attributes.
If you show the left and right image here, I can help you with exact code.

```
.bg{
   background-image:url("path_to_repeating_bg");background-repeat:repeat-x;width:auto}
}

<div id="banner" style="clear:both">
   <div style="float:left">
      <img src="<left_img_path>" />
   </div>
   <div class="bg" style="float:left;width:auto">  
   </div>
   <div style="float:left">
      <img src="<right_img_path>" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DpSnk/)

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="part1">

    </div>

    <div class="part2">

    </div>

    <div class="part3">

   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.banner{
    width:100%; 
}
div{
    display:inline;
    height:100px;
    solid:red;
    float:left;
}
div.part1{
    width:2%;
    border-raduis:5px;
    background:red;
}
div.part3{
    width:2%;
    background:red;
}
div.part2{
    width:96%;
    background:blue;
}
```

just change the background of the part1 ,part2 and part3 to the background images you have.